# How to make datatable blank in Vb.net?

Tags: vb.net, datatable

I have a data table which has few rows and columns. I need to delete the entire data along with column names also.

Eg :

```
                 Item | 2017 | 2018 | 2019 | 2020
                ----------------------------------
                 A      400    200   300     500
                 B      400    300   500     100
                 C      100    200   500     300
                 D      100    300   400     100
```

I need to delete all the data of the above data table along with the column names so that I can re-use the same data table for storing other values.

I tried datatable.clear() method it is clearing only the data, the column names remain intact and also I can't use dispose().

How can I do it.?

Comment: What happened to `dt As New DataTable`? Is it not working for u, for an already initialized `dt`?

Comment: Have you tried `datatable = Nothing` ?

Comment: I have already intialized it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Short version here:

```
Dim dt As New DataTable

'...
'you do some operations
'...

dt = New DataTable 'renew the same instance
```

Alternatively, you can use:

```
dt = Nothing 'basically setting it to NULL
```

Answer (score 9):

This should work:

```
datatable.Clear()             'clear records
datatable.Constraints.Clear() 'clear constraints (required before Columns.Clear(), if there is any constraint)
datatable.Columns.Clear()     'clear columns
```

Or this:

```
datatable.Reset()
```

But if you want to just create a new "blank" instance, or in other words, reinitialize it:

```
datatable = New Datatable
```

Comment: Should work also in your case, but it won't do exactly the same. But there's a comprehensive documentation. Just select `Reset()` in your code in Visual Studio and press `F1` ;-)

Answer (score 1):

The solution that work for me is the following

```
datatable.Reset()
```